# Show image icon before the link text

Tags: html, .net

I am adding the link button and a image logo with that link dynamically from code behind. On the page it is showing linktext and then the image '[LinkText][Image]'. I want to show in the other manner like '[Image][LinkText]'. How we can implement it, please help.

Here is my code snippet:

```
HtmlGenericControl imgToAdd = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
                    imgToAdd.Attributes.Add("src", "../Images/Click.png");
                    imgToAdd.Attributes.Add("id", "img" + containerCountForLabels);
                    imgToAdd.Style.Add("height", "16px");
                    imgToAdd.Style.Add("vertical-align", "top");
                    HtmlGenericControl linkToAdd = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                    linkToAdd.Attributes.Add("id", "linkbtn" + containerCountForLabels);
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "5px");
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("margin-top", "6px");
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("margin-left", "10px");
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("margin-right", "10px");
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("font-size", "13px");
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("float", "left");
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("color", "white");
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("text-decoration", "underline");
                    linkToAdd.Style.Add("vertical-align", "top");
                    linkToAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ShowHideDiv('img" + containerCountForLabels + "','divMain" + containerCountForLabels + "');");
                    linkToAdd.InnerText = dtReportLocal.Rows[0]["SubExpenseName"].ToString();
                    linkToAdd.Controls.Add(imgToAdd);
                    divForLink.Controls.Add(linkToAdd);

                    containerCountForLabels++;
```

Comment: try to replace `linkToAdd.Controls.Add(imgToAdd);` by `divForLink.Controls.Add(imgToAdd);` and let me know if it works

Comment: Hi fmodos, Tried with the solution you mentioned above, but its now working. Here I am working in a loop to create the link along with the images.

Comment: if you can please post only the piece of html code that was generate by this code.

Comment: Here is the piece of code:

<a id="linkbtn0" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align:top;float:left;text-decoration:underline;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:5px;color:white;margin-right:10px;margin-top:6px;font-size:13px;" onclick="ShowHideDiv('img0','divMain0');">June Sub Expense<img src="../Images/Click.png" id="img0" style="height:16px;vertical-align:top;"></a>


Is there any way that I can add the image before the innertext of link??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why it shows before, but what you can do is to add the image and text as an `innerHTML` of the link instead using `InnerText`, something like the code below:

```
linkToAdd.InnerHTML =  "<img src='../Images/Click.png' id='img"+ containerCountForLabels+"' style='height:16px;vertical-align:top;'>"+dtReportLocal.Rows[0]["SubExpenseName"].ToString();
```